# Google Spanner | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, alpn, npn

So i have a problem that i've seen before but all attempts to use other fixes have not worked. I'm havinga problem with the Google Spanner, more specifically at the line:

```
SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder().build();
```

Where I receive the stack error of:

```
WARNING: Error for /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/helloworld/v1/rest
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.getClassForName(ServletInitializationParameters.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.fromServletConfig(ServletInitializationParameters.java:72)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.init(EndpointsServlet.java:56)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:139)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$NettyRpcChannelFactory.newSslContext(SpannerOptions.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$NettyRpcChannelFactory.newChannel(SpannerOptions.java:278)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.createChannel(SpannerOptions.java:252)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.createChannels(SpannerOptions.java:239)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.<init>(SpannerOptions.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.<init>(SpannerOptions.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$Builder.build(SpannerOptions.java:179)
    at com.example.b612.SpannerTools.<init>(SpannerTools.java)
    at com.example.b612.AsteroidList.<clinit>(AsteroidList.java)
    ... 42 more

Aug 16, 2017 5:13:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:139)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$NettyRpcChannelFactory.newSslContext(SpannerOptions.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$NettyRpcChannelFactory.newChannel(SpannerOptions.java:278)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.createChannel(SpannerOptions.java:252)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.createChannels(SpannerOptions.java:239)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.<init>(SpannerOptions.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions.<init>(SpannerOptions.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions$Builder.build(SpannerOptions.java:179)
    at com.example.b612.SpannerTools.<init>(SpannerTools.java)
    at com.example.b612.AsteroidList.<clinit>(AsteroidList.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.getClassForName(ServletInitializationParameters.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.ServletInitializationParameters.fromServletConfig(ServletInitializationParameters.java:72)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.init(EndpointsServlet.java:56)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I've tried adding maven dependencies and such but each time it's done nothing to fix the error i keep receiving. I'm using an app engine with endpoints, and later this app engine will kick off a compute engine. Here is my current pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.example.b612</groupId>
    <artifactId>AsteroidEndpointTest</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <!-- Uncomment to use Endpoints Frameworks v1.0 and comment the v2.0 section -->
        <!--<dependency>
              <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
              <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.53</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- End of Endpoints Frameworks v1.0 -->
        <!-- Endpoints Frameworks v2.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End of Endpoints Frameworks v2.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.1-beta</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> <!-- exclude an old version of Guava -->
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.1-alpha</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev154-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-oauth-client-appengine</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
<version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
<artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
<version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
<artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
<version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>joda-time</groupId>
<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
<version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20151123</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
<artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
<artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
<artifactId>gax</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- deploy configuration -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- plugin configuration -->
                    <hostname>better-world-175517.appspot.com</hostname>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help or suggestions you can provide are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Cloud Spanner Documentation:

> The Cloud Spanner client libraries mentioned on this page are supported on Google Compute Engine (GCE), Google App Engine - Flexible Environment, Google Container Engine (GKE), and Google Cloud Functions. The Cloud Spanner client library for Java is supported on Google App Engine - Standard environment Java 8 Beta.
>
> If you are using Google App Engine - Standard environment Java 7, or Google App Engine - Standard environment with Go, PHP, or Python, use the REST Interface to access Cloud Spanner.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries

As far as I can see, you are trying to use the Java library in combination with Java 7, which is not supported.

Comment: i'm using the java8 beta, so switch the maven compiler source and target? it did not fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: found the error, had to add <runtime>java8</runtime> to the appengine-web.xml