# Spring with Google Spanner raise error

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to connect to Google Spanner with java using spring boot.
I wan't to read something from database and send it with web socket.
Currently I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SpannerServiceApplication extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpannerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseClient spannerDatabase(){
        SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("p").build();
        Spanner spanner = options.getService();
        return spanner.getDatabaseClient(DatabaseId.of(options.getProjectId(), "test123", "test"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/backend").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

and pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Switch to Jetty and netty-tcnative-boringssl-static did not help.
My error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) on project SpannerService: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'spannerDataba
se' defined in com.SpannerService.SpannerServiceApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClient]: Factory met
hod 'spannerDatabase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured. -> [Help 1]
```

Spring boot 2.0, Java 1.8, Tomcat 8.5.16
What's wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723174/google-spanner-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-jetty-alpn-npn-has-not-been)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did to make it work:
I upgraded java version from update 122 to 144(newest),
changed pom into this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```